# Python - Renaming path using values from a dictionary (for loop)

Tags: python, dictionary, path, rename, glob

I am renaming a batch of photos. I have a list of the image number (from the camera) and the appropriate name (to be the new name) in a CSV.
So far, I have got the csv import in just fine. It imports it as a dictionary with the image name as the "key", and the text as the new name as the "value".

THE PROBLEM:
When using the "key" appended to the path, it works just fine. BUT when using the "value", I get an empty list. When calling the type, it says string.

```
import os
from os.path import dirname
import glob

path = r"C:\Users...\Rename"
```

All the relevant files are in this "Rename" folder

```
import csv
with open('Rename\Rename.csv', mode='r') as infile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
with open('Rename\Rename_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

Print gives:

{'DSC01162.JPG': 'WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Dry', 'DSC01164.JPG': 'WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Wet'}

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    value = list(mydict.values())[0]
```

print(key, value) gives:

DSC01162.JPG WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Dry
DSC01164.JPG WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Dry

```
    old_file = glob.glob(path + "/" + key)
    new_file = glob.glob(path + "/" + value)
```

Printing the old_file gives the correct:
**['C:\...Rename/DSC01162.JPG']**

Whereas printing new_file gives and empty list:
**[]**

Once I get this correct, I will use:

```
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

**Any ideas on how to get the "new_file" address correct?**

I'm not that great on python so some completely different method may be too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually got when you're trying to get the old_file and rename new_file (if it is inside or outside the for loop), but I have somethings to point out:

First: it looks like you're on `Windows`, so try to keep the same folder style: use `'\'` instead of `'/'`.

Second: On your `for loop`, you're already returning the `key` and `values`, so that statement `value = list(mydict.values())[0]` is unecessary.

Then, on your `for loop`, you could rename the old file names right there:

```py
for key, value in mydict.items():
    old_file = glob.glob(path + "/" + key)
    new_file = glob.glob(path + "/" + value)
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the "\" comment, I was lazy and just copied from the windows explorer bar. I switch between a mac and windows as well. Thanks for your code, it works and now so does my code.

Comment: Glad to help! If you don't mind, kindly upvote the answer or mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the old and the new names in a dictionary (`mydict`), you don't need a `list()`. You can do something like this:

```
import os

path = r".\rename"
mydict = {'DSC01162.JPG': 'WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Dry', 'DSC01164.JPG': 'WI-22-62_Bx1-4_5.45-14.45m_Wet'}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    old_file = os.path.join(path, key)
    new_file = os.path.join(path, value + '.JPG')
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

If I understood the question correctly, that would make the job done.

Comment: This does indeed get the job done. Thanks so much.